# how to draw 8bit colored pixel in java programming

Tags: rgb, java-2d

I am trying to display pixel with 8 bit color using setRgb and getRgb methods but i am not getting

therefore please help me with program by using set and get rgb method 
and also any books related to pixel level modification in java 
thanking you

Comment: pls what you have done so far?